# VBA trouble with strerror / strncpy on OSX

Tags: excel, vba, macos, declaration, libc

My Excel spreadsheet is locking up everytime I use this code. Normally that means a declaration or call error of some sort, (an error of ignorance) but I haven't identified it yet.

This example VBA function SystemErrorText is supposed to return the text of the system error message for errno 2: file not found. It doesn't: it never returns from the call to strncpy

```
'char *strerror(int errnum);
Public Declare Function osx_strErrorlp Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "strerror" _
    (ByVal errnum As Long) As Long

'char *strncpy(char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src, size_t len);
Public Declare Function osx_strncpy Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "strncpy" _
    (ByVal strDestination As String, ByVal strSource As String, destlen As Long) As Long

Public Function SystemErrorText() As String
Dim ErrorText As String
Dim nLen As Long
Dim longpointer As Long
Dim lngptr2 As Long

longpointer = osx_strErrorlp(2)
ErrorText = String(256, Chr(0))
nLen = 255
lngptr2 = osx_strncpy(ErrorText, longpointer, nLen)
SystemErrorText = ErrorText

End Function
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong? I'm getting a pointer from strerror, which I assume is correct (perhaps the error is there?), but I'm not sure if that matters: I'm only trying to copy some bytes from that location.

I can't guarantee that the c declarations I've included as comments are valid for OS X: I've been given them, but I don't have a source that guarantees they are valid for OS X.  I'm using a 32 bit version of Excel for Mac: pointers are 32 bit, as are longs. Unlike the Windows version of Excel, the Mac version does not protect against stack errors on calls to library functions: it just crashes. And for some reason, err.LastDLLerror isn't connected to errno (not that it matters for this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration is wrong for the way it is used:

```
Public Declare Function osx_strncpy Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "strncpy" _
    (ByVal strDestination As String, ByVal strSource As String, destlen As Long) As Long
```

"strSource" is declared as a ByVal String.  That means that a pointer to a null terminated string will be passed to the libc function (good).  But it also means that the *VBA code will be accepting and requiring a BSTR parameter* (bad).

Where the function is called:

```
lngptr2 = osx_strncpy(ErrorText, longpointer, nLen)
```

... the longpointer value is first implicitly converted to a BSTR. Then the value of that bSTR (the  <sub>address of the null terminated string containing a</sub>  textual representation of the pointer value) is passed to the libc function.

So strncpy is copying from a local temporary memory area to the destination, not copying from the error string to the destination.  Why this causes Excel to crash is unknown: in the same situation, strlcpy doesn't crash. But that's not important: even if did work, it's not what was wanted.

Note that the declaration isn't "wrong", it would work correctly for

```
text1 = "A"
text2 = String(2,chr(0))
osx_strncpy(text2, text1, Len(text1))
```

--  it's just not what is wanted. The requirement is for a function that accepts a pointer value:

```
Public Declare Function osx_strncpy_lp Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "strncpy" _
    (ByVal strDestination As String, ByVal strSource_lp As Long, destlen As Long) As Long
```

<sub>And you could even make the original declaration work, by declaring a string object, then overwriting it's internal value with the pointer value you want to use.  But if you did that, you could just use a VBA assignment statement to copy the kludged string object</sub>